# waitFor in react testing-library not entered

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, testing-library

I am writing a test for a react component. When I click on the component its content gets hidden.
Here is the code of the test:

```js
it('Click to hide minitoc root', async () => {
    const { app } = render(<App />);
    const inThisPage = screen.getByTitle('click here to fold/unfold the mini table of contents')
    const minitocRoot = screen.getByTitle('minitoc root')
    // console.log(inThisPage) // shows <ref *1> HTMLDivElement {...
    // console.log( minitocRoot) // shows <ref *1> HTMLParagraphElement {...
    fireEvent.click(inThisPage)
    console.log('aaaaaa')
    await waitFor(() => {
        ()=> {
              console.log('rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr')  // this never shows 
              expect(getComputedStyle(minitocRoot).display).toBe('none')
             }
        }
      );
      expect(getComputedStyle(minitocRoot).display).toBe('none') // this triggers an error
      console.log('zzzzzz')
 });
```

It appears the code never enters the waitFor section. The `console.log('rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr')` never shows up.

- If I omit the second expect, the test passes.
- If I include the second expect, the test fails (expects 'block', not 'none')

inThisPage is a JSX div tag, and minitocRoot is a JSX p tag (verified using console.log)

Here is the JSX code of the component:

```html
        <div
            id='minitoc'
            className={foldedOrNotCSS()}
            style={{ width: widthInPageForToc - 20 }}
        >
            {/* These p tags are hidden, they are like a message board to pass values from React to jQuery */}
            <p id='contentSelector' className='passValueFromReactToJquery'>
                {contentSelector}
            </p>
            <p id='levelsToShow' className='passValueFromReactToJquery'>
                {levelsToShow}
            </p>
            <p id='widthInPageForToc' className='passValueFromReactToJquery'>
                {widthInPageForToc}
            </p>
            <p id='tagsToHideToc' className='passValueFromReactToJquery'>
                {JSON.stringify(tagsToHideToc)}
            </p>

            {/* The "In this page" header of the minitoc, where the user clicks to fold/unfold  */}
            <p
                title='click here to fold/unfold the mini table of contents'
                onClick={handleOpenClose}
                className='inThisPage'
            >
                In this page:{' '}
                <span className='openCloseIcon'>&nbsp;{openCloseIcon()}&nbsp;</span>
            </p>

            {/* This is where the minitoc is going to build  */}
            <div id='minitoc_root' title='minitoc root'></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working for me:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false)
  const handleOpenClose = () => {
    console.log('open close')
    setCollapsed(!collapsed)
  }

  return (
    <div id="minitoc">
      <p
        title="click here to fold/unfold the mini table of contents"
        onClick={handleOpenClose}
        className="inThisPage"
      >
        openCloseIcon
      </p>
      <div
        id="minitoc_root"
        title="minitoc root"
        style={{ display: collapsed ? 'none' : 'block' }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

```
import { render, screen, waitFor, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import App from './MiniTock'

test('renders learn react link', async () => {
  render(<App />)
  const inThisPage = screen.getByTitle('click here to fold/unfold the mini table of contents')
  const minitocRoot = screen.getByTitle('minitoc root')
  expect(getComputedStyle(minitocRoot).display).toBe('block') // this triggers an error
  fireEvent.click(inThisPage)
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(getComputedStyle(minitocRoot).display).toBe('none')
  })
})
```

Comment: Well when I write it like that, the test passes. But it looks like the second expect never triggers. If I add a console.log beside it, it never shows up. If I repeat the `expect(...)`  after the `await waitFor()`, that triggers an error.

Comment: I changed the expect to 'flex' inside the waitFor and the test fails on timeout as expected so it is working

Comment: I copied your code and it does work. Right now I can't see how my original is fundamentally different... I'll try intermediary versions to see where the problem arises.

Comment: It turns out I had 
``` 
await waitFor(() => {
  ()=> {
   expect(getComputedStyle(minitocRoot).display).toBe('flex')
  }
  }
  
   );
```
instead of 
```
await waitFor(() => { expect(getComputedStyle(minitocRoot).display).toBe('flex')} );
```